# Binding Style to DataGridTextColumns ElementStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a datagrid with some objects. The objects have a name, a "type" property and a bunch of irrelevant properties.

based on if the type is "MaterialType" or not i want to set a style for the cells textblock (bold & intend 10px)

I started out with a converter. => it gets the type and converts to a font-weight.

```
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{Binding type, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=TypeToFontWeightConverter}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,0,0,0"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

It works.. but I only got to set the font-weight.

I want an individual style.

so I edited my converter into a TypeToStyle Converter

```
    class TypeToStyleConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {

            Style style = new Style(typeof(TextBlock));

            if (value is Type && value == typeof(MaterialType))
            {
                style.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold));
                style.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.PaddingProperty, new Thickness(0)));
            }
            else
            {
                style.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold));
                style.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.PaddingProperty, new Thickness(10,0,0,0)));
            }
            return style;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Then I bind the converter.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"
                    Header="Name"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Width="1*"
                    ElementStyle="{Binding type, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=TypeToStyleConverter}}"/>
```

It all compiles fine. But no styles. The converter doesn't get triggered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to look into using a [StyleSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.styleselector.aspx) instead of a Converter.

Comment: It's great that @VDP understood this answer, unfortunately I don't understand how to implement it. Can anyone give me more details?